# CSS - spacing next to button is different on IE than in Chrome. How do I fix this?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm not too good with CSS and am having trouble with it on Internet Explorer.
It looks like there are partial issues with Flexbox in IE and "CanIUse" said to use `display: -ms-flexbox` but I think it might be something else.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwtJr.png) - The left is IE, the right is Chrome.

Why is the spacing different on IE and how do I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<section id="employee-directory">
    <h4>Directory Search</h4>
    <p class="search-by">Search by first or last name</p>

    <form class="search-form">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="search-box" class="search" placeholder="Search Name" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ul class="suggestions"></ul>
    </form>

    <div id="directory-results">
        <p class="incorrect-info">Incorrect Information?<br>Please contact IT Support.</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#employee-directory {
    background: rgb( 227, 227, 227);
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 2px 6px 6px 10px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 230px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#employee-directory h4 {
    color: rgb(0, 75, 141);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#employee-directory p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

input {
    padding: 5px;
}

input.search {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0;
    border: 2px solid #F7F7F7;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.search-container {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}

#search-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so strange but I've found a workaround is that setting search-button's with over 20%.Then it will work well in IE as it on Chrome. I guess that maybe IE's behaviour to render the page is a bit different from chrome.

```
#search-button {
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
```

}

[image: result]